# why browser request for image after ajax?

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, browser

I'm using backbone and nodejs for a single page webapp.

I got a view, which has a model(a blog post) in it. when user click on 'like' button, the view  will start ajax send the user'id to server to let the like number +1.

it looks like this:

```
        this.model.save({
            likedBy: userModel.get('_id')
        }, {
            url: '/posts/' + this.model.get('_id') + '/like',
            success: function() {
                // do something
            },
            patch: true
        });
```

my problem is, when this code got run. browser start http request to retrieve all the images on the screen, and re-render them. so the screen got a "shake" after user clicked the like button.

this is not happening everywhere, but what caused this? how to stop the "shake"?

thanks for any advance.

Comment: save triggers a 'sync' event, might that be heard by some other listener, resulting in an action?  If it's just a like, rather than saving the model for persistence, I might be more explicit and send an http post request using jQuery (eg. `$.post()`) rather than repurposing backbone's `save` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this.model.save() the model will update his data in the server and will call your view's render function. The render method will create a new DOM element and replace the old DOM element, that's what causing the flickering (it requests the images again).

I assume you have an API call for Like action (if not it's better to have one) so you can make a sperate AJAX call for like action on your model by adding a function like so:

```
addLike : function(data) {
 Backbone.ajax({
            url: '/api/like/'+ this.get('id'),
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: options.success,
            error: options.error
        });
```

}

Comment: Thanks Elad, you're right. I wish I could work this out more 'Backbony'. but, I think this could be one answer for the "why don't use framework" question